# Javascript - Retrieve input value from a selected checkbox and do something with it

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am new to javascript and looking for some help. I have searched around different forums but my skills have not served me well to build a working script.

I have a simple form with 4 checkboxes and a submit button. Each checbox has a unique value. The value is part of a URL for which when the submit button is clicked the value of the selected checkbox is used to build the link. It should also open the link in a new window.

Here is my HTML

```
<form name="Form">  
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="001"><label>box1</label><BR>  
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="002"><label>box2</label><BR>  
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="003"><label>box3</label><BR>
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="004"><label>box4</label><BR>
<br>
<input type="button" value="submit" name="butt" onclick="submit()">
</form>
```

Here is what I need the Javascript to do:

If checkbox is ticked
Get input value
Use input value to open a link
Base link is for example "http://example.com/"
If multiple checkboxes are ticked and i click submit i would like it to open the links
The final action would be for example if I checked box1 and clicked submit to open the link in new window i.e. http://example.com/001

Or if I checked multple boxed and clicked submit it would open all the links seperately.

Here is the Javascript function I attempted from different forums - it's missing bits and pieces and probably needs rewriting.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit(){

var boxes = document.getElementsByName('box');
var url = "http://www.example.com/";

if ( box.checked === true ) {

}

var box;
for (var i = 0, length = boxes.length; i < length; i++) {
  if (boxes[i].checked) {
    // do whatever you want with the checked radio
    box = labels[i].innerHTML;
    window.alert(url + input-value-goes-here );
  }
}
}
</script>
```

EDIT: I completely forgot to mention that I would prefer not to have to enter each value in the javascript. If you can imagine 100+ checkboxes.. it would be a nightmare to have to keep updating the script.

Thanks!

Appreciate the assistance.

Moustafa

Comment: At Least show what script you have written to get input value and open a new tab, this will help you in learning

Comment: Hi Iti, I just updated the post to include the incomplete javascript function that i've been working with. thanks!

Comment: use a javascript framework! such as jquery (or other). it easier to get the value of elements

Comment: should you link look like http://ex.com?box=001&box=002.....&box=n according of checked inputs?

Comment: The final link will be to a CSV file to download, it uses link + ?csv=1

I completely forgot to mention that I would prefer not to have to enter each value in the javascript. If you can imagine 100+ checkboxes.. it would be a nightmare to have to keep updating the script.

Comment: I just re read your question. Each box has a unique value and they are not tied together. Each check box should open a seperate window i.e. static link "http://www.domain.com/" + the input value from the checkbox "001" etc. Final link "http://www.domain.com/001"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function OpenAll()
{
alert("i am in");
var data = document.forms[0].box;
var i;
for (i=0;i<data.length;i++)
  {
  if (data[i].checked)
    {
    window.open(""+data[i].value);
    }
  }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <form method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="http://www.google.com">Google<br/>  
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="http://www.facebook.com">FaceBook<br/>  
<input type="submit" value="OPEN" onclick="OpenAll()"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works great on a new page but if i add the script to an existing page with other forms and checkboxes it doesnt work. I tried troubleshooting and I isolated it down to conflicts with other checkboxes. Will this javascript work with a specific form or any ideas why it may be failing? the alert pops up but just doesnt open the link.

Comment: If it helps.. Firefox debug displayed "Data is undefined"

Comment: I see. so if I have 3 forms and the one in question is my 3rd form then document.forms[2]

0,1,2,3.. 

and it worked! thank you again!!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I'm not sure if it's possible to open multiple tabs/windows within one method, as window.open will stop the current JavaScript-method running.</strike> It IS possible to open multiple windows, but there is a catch to it. You must enable pop-ups, which most people have disabled by default. Then there is the browser-issue: as a developer, you can't decide whether the browser opens up a new tab, or a new window. What you can do to show multiple tabs/windows, is use the piece of JavaScript I copied at the bottom of my answer. Note though, that while it works, it opens up only ONE tab, the rest are new 'pop-up'-windows (atleast in Chrome).

This code does work if you need to open one page, and one page only though.

Using jQuery might make your life a lot easier:

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="boxes.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="box1" id="box1"><label>box1</label><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box2" value="box2" id="box2"><label>box2</label><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box3" value="box3" id="box3"><label>box3</label><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box4" value="box4" id="box4"><label>box4</label><br/>

        <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submitButton" onclick="submit()">
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript (jQuery)

```
function submit() {
    var box1 = $('#box1');
    var box2 = $('#box2');
    var box3 = $('#box3');
    var box4 = $('#box4');

    if (box1.prop('checked')) {
        goToUrl('http://box1url.com');
        //Redirect by box1
    }
    if (box2.prop('checked')) {
        goToUrl('http://box2url.com');
        //Redirect by box2
    }
    if (box3.prop('checked')) {
        goToUrl('http://box3url.com');
        //Redirect by box3
    }
    if (box4.prop('checked')) {
        goToUrl('http://box4url.com');
        //Redirect by box4
    }
}

function goToUrl(url) {
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    win.focus();
}
```

**EDIT: WITHOUT JQUERY**

Might you decide not to use jQuery, you could use this for JavaScript:

```
function submit() {
    var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
    var box2 = document.getElementById('box2');
    var box3 = document.getElementById('box3');
    var box4 = document.getElementById('box4');

    if (box1.checked) {
        goToUrl('http://box1url.com');
        //Redirect by box1
    }
    if (box2.checked) {
        goToUrl('http://box2url.com');
        //Redirect by box2
    }
    if (box3.checked) {
        goToUrl('http://box3url.com');
        //Redirect by box3
    }
    if (box4.checked) {
        goToUrl('http://box4url.com');
        //Redirect by box4
    }
}

function goToUrl(url) {
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    win.focus();
}
```

**EDIT2: Added 'multi-url'**

```
var urls = []; //Initialize empty array
if (box1.checked) {
    urls.push('http://box1url.com'); // If box is checked, push the url
}

urls.forEach(function(url) {
    goToUrl(url); //Go to all URLs in a for-each loop
});
```

**EDIT3: Added more 'dynamic' URLs by values**

If setting the URL as a value for the checkbox, you can retrieve it in the JavaScript afterwards:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="http://box1url.com" id="box1"><label>box1</label><br/>
```

JavaScript (no jQuery):

```
if (box1.checked) {
        urls.push(box1.value);
        //Redirect by box1
}
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
if (box1.prop('checked')) {
        urls.push(box1.value);
        //Redirect by box1
}
```

**EDIT4: Full code**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="no-j-boxes.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box1" value="http://box1url.com" id="box1"><label>box1</label><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box2" value="http://box2url.com" id="box2"><label>box2</label><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box3" value="http://box3url.com" id="box3"><label>box3</label><br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="box4" value="http://box4url.com" id="box4"><label>box4</label><br/>

        <input type="button" value="Submit" name="submitButton" onclick="submit()">
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
function submit() {
    var box1 = document.getElementById('box1');
    var box2 = document.getElementById('box2');
    var box3 = document.getElementById('box3');
    var box4 = document.getElementById('box4');

    var urls = [];

    if (box1.checked) {
        urls.push(box1.value);
    }
    if (box2.checked) {
        urls.push(box2.value);
    }
    if (box3.checked) {
        urls.push(box3.value);
    }
    if (box4.checked) {
        urls.push(box4.value);
    }

    urls.forEach(function(url) {
        goToUrl(url);
    });
}

function goToUrl(url) {
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

Comment: Pim, wow, thanks for such a comprehensive reply and option to use Jquery. I have not played with jquery much but I will try it out.

I am very sorry that I completely forgot to mention that I would prefer not to have to enter each value in the javascript. If you can imagine 100+ checkboxes.. it would be a nightmare to have to keep updating the script.

Comment: I have added a way to retrieve the URL from the checkbox' value. Let's say you have a PHP script looping through the data needed to create the checkboxes, just let the loop set the value to the specific URL. You can then retrieve it using JavaScript afterwards by using `box1.value`. Hope this helped you :)

Comment: Pim, sorry what should the complete code look like.. I think you may have written what I am looking for but i am having trouble putting it all together. Can I trouble you to post the full code 'no jquery version'

Also, will this work with a submit button that I have? reading your code it seems the URL will open by just checking the box.

Comment: Another edit, although I might just clean the post up a little bit :). A tip to use if you want this to be more dynamic: use classes. Give your checkboxes a class, so you can forloop through those classes using `document.getElementsByClassName(className);` You can then forloop through the returned array with your checkboxes.

Comment: Glad to have helped you :)